# Erro unknown type name

Tags: c

Estou tentando passar uma typedef struct como parâmetro para uma função, mas dá o erro:
"bib.h:6:13: error: unknown type name ‘matriz’"
Aqui está o código:

```
#include "bib.h"

typedef struct
{
    int matriz[N][N];
}matriz;

void gerarMatriz(matriz m);

int
main()
{   
    matriz m1;

    gerarMatriz(m1);

    return(0);
}
```

E a biblioteca bib.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

void
gerarMatriz(matriz m)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (1 + rand() % 20));
    }
}
```

Ainda não estou fazendo nada com a struct na função! Só testando algumas coisas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em bib.h ele não reconhece essa variável `matriz` por ela ter sido criada no primeiro arquivo. Você precisaria fazer um `#include "main.c"` do primeiro arquivo ou então criar sua `struct` dentro do arquivo bib.h

Por exemplo, o arquivo bib.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

typedef struct {
    int matriz[N][N];
} Matriz;

void gerarMatriz(Matriz matriz){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d\n", (1 + rand() % 20));
}
```

E o arquivo main.c

```
#include "bib.h"

int main(){
    Matriz matriz;
    gerarMatriz(matriz);
    return 0;
}
```